# How to debug javascript (from the browser console) in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel-5

In Laravel, your javascript resides in:
resources
    -assets
        -js
          -app.js

then you usually run "$ npm run watch" (if your still developing) and then
the code gets "compiled" in:
public
   -js
    -app.js

But when you check your browser console the lines in red does not match the actual app.js located in your resource->assets->js folder.

Any suggestions to accurately debug javascript files in laravel?

Comment: From the browser console you can find out from which file actually the error is thrown out (you will find the path from the rigth side of the console exactly opp. of the error message). By which you can navigate to the source section and then go through the file path till the js file and check for the errors. This is one way.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I was focusing on the left side on the console and overlooked the one on the right side was actually giving the hint.